# Add a list in jsf page

Tags: java, jsf

My databale declaration

```
h:dataTable value="#{Bean.listname}" var="con2" border="1" width="3000" id="dt2"
```

List:

List consists of a collection of bean object.

Button

```
h:commandButton value="Add Contact Details" action="#{bean.addlist}"
```

My Requirement

If the user click add contact details I want to display a row in edit format where user enters the data. And then user wants to add one more contact means again he want click that button and there user can enter the data and so on.

My problem

If I declare the list as static list,the list or that datable correctly working it displays already entered data list or row + a empty row by list. But if multi users entering means the static list will cause problem (I think so).

If I am declaring list as non static list, if the user click add contact details button empty list or row added user enters the data. Again if  user want add one more means while clicking the add contact details button the entered data get cleared and new empty row or list appearing.

So please help me how to solve this problem...

Is any problem the way my query is if it is just comment pls...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

You have used in datatable the name "Bean" (with uppercase) and in the commandButton the name "bean" (with lowercase).

Please provide the java-code of your bean.